# Retaining value of a dropdown list from an autorefreshing page PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a page which needs to be autorefreshed every 5 seconds. However, the things which needs to be displayed within the page relies on the value from a dropdown list. How do I make it so that the selected value is retained every time the page gets refreshed?

Code for Dropdown:

```
$query="SELECT eventName,eventID FROM event WHERE eventStatus = 'Ongoing' ORDER BY eventDate";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name='event2'>";
$event = strip_tags(@$_POST['event2']);
echo "<option>---------------------Select---------------------</option>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $selected = false;
   // check if the current value equals the value submited
   if(@$_POST['event2'] == $nt['eventID']){
       $selected = true;
   }

   // show selected attribute only if $selected is true
   echo "<option value='{$nt['eventID']}' ". ($selected ? "selected" : "") .">{$nt['eventName']}</option>";
}
echo "</select><input type='submit' name ='view' value='View'/>";
```

The code above manages to retain the value of the dropdown only if I make a submission and then I am redirected to the same page that contains the dropdown. However, it does not apply when the page refreshes itself automatically.

Comment: How does the page refresh itself?  You may need to use ajax..

Comment: The page refreshes itself using  header('Refresh: 5');

Comment: So you only give them five seconds to make a selection on the dropdown list?

Comment: once a user selects something, a table will be generated, then the page starts to refresh every 5 seconds so that the table is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of refreshing the entire page, you can just use jquery to load and display certain poption of throw page via ajax ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This way, the portion of the page that houses the form never gets refreshed, just the table that displays the data.

Use the javascript settimeout method to run the ajax call every five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ajax for refreshing purpose, but you can still store data into SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh statement is different than the JQuery reload function.

I used the JQuery reload function in a similar situation and it provided the desired result where refresh failed.

Try:

```
function reloadPage() { 
    location.reload();
    };

$(document).ready(function() {  
    setTimeout("reloadPage()", 5000);
    });
```

I haven't tested it so please let me know if this works.

Sincerely,
Kevin

Comment: Hi kevin. I tested it but it produces the same result as before.

Comment: jQuery does not have a `reload` method.  You mean JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a cookie.